# How to link HTML file to CSS

Tags: html, css, hyperlink

I am a beginner in HTML and learning to code via Sololearn.com
They have HTML,CSS,& JavaScript and with Output, all linked together.
I am using Sublime Text Editor, and this does not have this facility.
Thus, have to create a separate CSS file. This is where I am not sure how to do this.

By creating a new file in STE, and by typing <ht and hitting the return key, the following code appears:

```
\<!DOCTYPE html\>
```

<html>
<head>

```
\<meta charger=“utf-8”\>
```

<meta

```
name=“viewport”  content=“width= 

device-width,
```

initial– scale=1”>
< title>

```
\</title\>
```

</head>
<body></ body>

```
\</html\>
```

I have tried numerous places to find out this problem, of mine without any success.
I greatly appreciate your feedback.
Thank you in advance.
Khalid

I have tried numerous websites without any success.
My issue is how to link HTML file to a CSS file.